# React how to fix stale state in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Creating multiple child components, which each can setState of its parent, makes these child components have different versions of history of the state (aka stale state)

To reproduce the error:

1. create 2 child components by clicking "add new social media"
2. submit both child components to set parent state
3. submit the firstly created component again, and now the second component input disappears from the resulting state

Another error:

1. create 2 child components by clicking "add new social media"
2. submit the secondly created child component
3. submit the firstly created child component, and now the second component input disappears from the resulting state

All in all, I want the resulting state to have ALL the data of each components. How can I fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fog-oz10p

```
const Admin = () => {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState({});
  const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState([]);

  const updateLinks = (socialMedia, url) => {
    setLinks({
      ...links,
      [socialMedia]: url
    });
  };

  const linkData = {
    links,
    updateLinks
  };

  const applyChanges = () => {
    console.log(links);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {newLink ? newLink.map(child => child) : null}
      <div className="container-sm">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            setNewLink([
              ...newLink,
              <AddNewLink key={Math.random()} linkData={linkData} />
            ]);
          }}
        >
          Add new social media
        </Button>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}
          onClick={() => applyChanges()}
        >
          Apply Changes
        </Button>
        <h3>{JSON.stringify(links, null, 4)}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

```
const AddNewLink = props => {
  const [socialMedia, setSocialMedia] = useState("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const { updateLinks } = props.linkData;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    updateLinks(socialMedia, url);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl
        style={{ marginTop: "30px", marginLeft: "35px", width: "90%" }}
      >
        <InputLabel>Select Social Media</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={socialMedia}
          onChange={e => {
            setSocialMedia(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"facebook"}>Facebook</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"instagram"}>Instagram</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"tiktok"}>TikTok</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <form
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        style={{ marginBottom: "30px", marginLeft: "35px" }}
      >
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Enter link"
          style={{ width: "95%" }}
          onChange={e => {
            setUrl(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
      <div className="container-sm">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          style={{ marginBottom: "30px" }}
          onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddNewLink;
```

Comment: Please use the on-site Stack Snippets for runnable examples rather than (or in addition to) external sites. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (You do have to use `<React.Fragment>` rather than `<>`, sadly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is caused by `updateLinks()` function *closing over* the `links` state.

When you create two `AddNewLink` components, each of them is passed `updateLinks()` function. Since initially, `links` is an empty object, `updateLinks()` function passed to both instances of `AddNewLink`, has a closure over the `links` variable and `links` at that time refers to an empty object `{}`. So when you submit the form, as far as `updateLinks()` function is concerned, `links` is an empty object. So when merging `links` with the data passed from `AddNewLink` component, only the data from the submitted form is saved in the state because `links` is an empty object.

**Solution:**

You could use `useRef` hook to access the latest value of `links` inside `updateLinks()` function.

```
const Admin = () => {
   ...
   
   const linkRef = useRef();

   const updateLinks = (socialMedia, url) => {
      linkRef.current = { ...linkRef.current, [socialMedia]: url };
      setLinks(linkRef.current);
   };
   
   ...
};
```

Also i don't think you need more than one instance of `AddNewLink` component. You could add more than one social media link in the state with only a single instance of `AddNewLink` component.

**Demo:**

[image: Edit sharp-tdd-hym00]